# Check to see if a variable is empty (multiple checks!)

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am trying to run something if A is the same as B and B is not empty. I can do this check manually before I do thi -NE, but I rather do this in the same check.

```
if($($ADEmployee.mobile) -ne $($ListEmployee.mobile) -and (!$($ListEmployee.mobile)))
{
  do someething
}
```

can this be done?

Comment: If $ADEmployee.mobile will always have a value then checking $ListEmployee.mobile for $null is pointless.

Comment: I tested of course.. I just wanted to show what I had already done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (($ademployee.mobile,$null -like $listemployee.mobile)[0]){
      do something
      }
```

Not that I'd ever actually do that in code.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do that in code? Bad coding? How should I do it? 
My situation is that I have a CSV file with "mobile" fields that I would like to replace the "mobile" property in AD except for when the field in my list is empty..

Comment: If the list side matches the ad side it will return that. If "that" is something other than $null it will evaluate as $true. If the list side is null, it will return $null, and that will evaluate as $false. If both the ad side and the list side are $null it's going to return a pair of nulls, so the [0] keeps it from trying to evaluate an array. The end result is it will only evaluate to $true if the AD side mathes the List side, and whatever is matching is not $null.

Comment: I'd probably do this: if ($listemployee.mobile){$admployee.mobile = $listemployee.mobile)

Comment: Actully, I probably do this: if ($listemployee.mobile -match '\S'){$ademployee.mobile = $listemployee.mobile}  Been bit too many times.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would check if "empty" first then check the other object for "not empty". Subexpressions are not necessary:

```
if (!$ListEmployee.mobile -and $ADEmployee.mobile)
{
    do someething
}
```

**Update:**
$( ... ) is a subexpression. Try the following then:

```
if ($ListEmployee.mobile -and $ListEmployee.mobile -ne $ADEmployee.mobile) 
{
    $ADEmployee.mobile = $ListEmployee.mobile
}
```

Comment: I was a bit too quick.. That didn't work unfortunately. 
What I would like to do is replace the info in $ADemployee.mobile with $listemployee.mobile EXCEPT if $listemployee.mobile is empty..

Answer (score 0):

I feel using IsNullOrEmpty method of system.string object is more appropriate for checking null or empty values. It also has method to check if a string is formed by only white spaces which is useful. See http://techibee.com/powershell/check-if-a-string-is-null-or-empty-using-powershell/1889 for more details.